# Indefinitely Looping ? Check Two Printers if Online or Offline - Send Email if Down

Tags: ksh, aix

I have this script that is looping indefinitely - there are two printers to check once each - printer01 and printer02.  If they are DOWN or OFF then send an email.
Why is it looping indefinitely on the first printer01?

```
#!/bin/ksh
c=1
while [[ $c -le 3 ]]; do
STATUS=$(lpstat -printer0$c| grep 'READY' | awk '{print $3}')

if [[  ! $STATUS == "DOWN" ||! $STATUS == "OFF" ]] ; then

        #create email summary and send

        today=`date +%m%d%Y`

        echo "*** START EMAIL SUMMARY ***                                    " > /lsf10/monitors/lpstat_email_$today.txt
        echo "*                                                              " >> /lsf10/monitors/lpstat_email_$today.txt
        echo "* Date - `date`                                                " >> /lsf10/monitors/lpstat_email_$today.txt
        echo "*                                                              " >> /lsf10/monitors/lpstat_email_$today.txt
        echo "* Start time   => $s_time                                      " >> /lsf10/monitors/lpstat_email_$today.txt
        echo "* Current time => `date +%H:%M:%S`                             " >> /lsf10/monitors/lpstat_email_$today.txt
        echo "*                                                              " >> /lsf10/monitors/lpstat_email_$today.txt
        echo "* Printer email message will be here for you to modify         " >> /lsf10/monitors/lpstat_email_$today.txt
        echo "* Please investigate.                                          " >> /lsf10/monitors/lpstat_email_$today.txt
        echo "*                                                              " >> /lsf10/monitors/lpstat_email_$today.txt
        echo "*** END EMAIL SUMMARY ***                                      " >> /lsf10/monitors/lpstat_email_$today.txt

        `mail -s "Mobius Printer Down Alert!" "email1,email2" < /lsf10/monitors/lpstat_email_$today.txt`
fi
c = $c + 1
done
exit
```

Comment: Don't put backticks around the `mail` command: that will execute the command, substitute the output, and then _try to execute the output as a command_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider adding error checking after each external command.

You can use `ksh -x`  to run your script to see your mistake, this turns on debugging mode. You can also do this by adding `set -x` inside the script.

Your script is looping because the variable $c is not being set the way you think.

You might want to check the exit code ($?) from each external command, and also check that the stdout returned by `lpstat` is not empty or any error, and verify that the mail program is on the PATH and executable etc.

Try a different approach, something like this:

```
#!/bin/ksh
typeset +i c=1 
while (( c <= 2 )); do
    STATUS=$(lpstat -printer0$c| grep 'READY' | awk '{print $3}')
    if [[  ! $STATUS == "DOWN" ||! $STATUS == "OFF" ]] ; then
        #create email summary and send

        today=`date +%m%d%Y`
        outfile=/tmp/lpstat_email_$today.txt  # use your own path

        echo "*** START EMAIL SUMMARY ***                                    " > ${outfile}
        echo "*                                                              " >> ${outfile}
        echo "* Date - `date`                                                " >> ${outfile}
        echo "*                                                              " >> ${outfile}
        echo "* Start time   => $s_time                                      " >> ${outfile}
        echo "* Current time => `date +%H:%M:%S`                             " >> ${outfile}
        echo "*                                                              " >> ${outfile}
        echo "* Printer email message will be here for you to modify         " >> ${outfile}
        echo "* Please investigate.                                          " >> ${outfile}
        echo "*                                                              " >> ${outfile}
        echo "*** END EMAIL SUMMARY ***                                      " >> ${outfile}

        `mail -s "Mobius Printer Down Alert!" "email1,email2" < ${outfile}`
    fi  
    let c=$(( c + 1 ))
done
exit
```